# String replacements

Tags: swift

My question is how if i want to replace whole line of the tag `<h1>.....</h1>` in to a empty string `""` .

```
var s = "<h1 style=\"font-family: Helvetica\">Hello Pizza</h1><p>Tap the buttons above to see <strong>some cool stuff</strong> with <code>UIWebView</code><p><img src=\"https://apppie.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/photo-sep-14-7-40-59-pm_small1.jpg\">"
var search = "<\\/?strong>"
var replaceWith = ""
var replacementLength = count(replaceWith)
var err: NSError? = nil

var expr = NSRegularExpression(pattern: search, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &err)

if let matches = expr?.matchesInString(s, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(s)) ) {
    var replacedStringLengthDifference = 0
    for match in matches {
        var startIndex = advance(s.startIndex, (match.range.location + replacedStringLengthDifference))
        var endIndex = advance(s.startIndex, (match.range.length + match.range.location + replacedStringLengthDifference))
        replacedStringLengthDifference -= (match.range.length - replacementLength)
        s.replaceRange(startIndex..<endIndex, with: replaceWith)
    }
}

println(s)
```

Result:

`<h1 style="font-family: Helvetica">Hello Pizza</h1><p>Tap the buttons above to see some cool stuff with <code>UIWebView</code><p><img src="https://apppie.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/photo-sep-14-7-40-59-pm_small1.jpg">`

Comment: If I understood correctly, your code remove the Strong content. So your issue is to use a RegularExpression (the equivalent of your "search"), with something like "<h1 possiblesOthersValues> possiblesOthersValues</h1>" ? So In my opinion, that's a Regex issue. So what have you tried for that regex?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var s = "<h1 style=\"font-family: Helvetica\">Hello Pizza</h1><p>Tap the buttons above to see <strong>some cool stuff</strong> with <code>UIWebView</code><p><img src=\"https://apppie.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/photo-sep-14-7-40-59-pm_small1.jpg\">"

let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<h1 .*?>.*?</h1>", options: .CaseInsensitive , error: nil)!
let result = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(s, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, (s as NSString).length), withTemplate: "")

// -> <p>Tap the buttons above to see <strong>some cool stuff</strong> with <code>UIWebView</code><p><img src="https://apppie.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/photo-sep-14-7-40-59-pm_small1.jpg">
```

Note that, this replaces all occurrences of `<h1 ...>...</h1>` in the string. If you want to replace only the first:

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<h1 .*?>.*?</h1>", options: .CaseInsensitive , error: nil)!
let range = regex.rangeOfFirstMatchInString(s, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, (s as NSString).length))
let result = (s as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: "")
```

Note that, this works for your string, but not for every HTML string: see [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)